# Mark async methods that just return a Task with the Conditional attribute?

Tags: c#, async-await

The `System.Diagnostics.ConditionalAttribute` is really useful for sectioning off pieces of Debug code without needing to use compiler directives but it is only compatible with methods that return `void`.
Is there a way to use it (or something equivalent) for async methods that return a `Task`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No.

A void method can be removed without any problem because the net effect on the evaluation stack is the same whether there is a method call there or not: zero.

A non-void method cannot be removed because in the case where it is removed, there are zero things on the stack, and in the case where it is not removed, there is one thing on the stack: a reference to a task.

Put another way: what would you expect this to do:

```
Foo(BarAsync());
```

if `Foo` takes a `Task` and `BarAsync` is removed?

Comment: `what would you expect this to do[...]?` I suppose they could make it so that it's an error to use the return value of `BarAsync` in any code that doesn't *also* have the same attribute.  I don't think that it would end up being worth the effort to implement this behavior though.

Comment: I would expect it to do `Foo((Task)Task.FromResult(0));`, just like every modern mocking library does.

Comment: @StephenCleary: And why that rather than `default(Task)`?  What to do if the method returns a type other than `Task` -- `ValueTask`, say; how many types get special treatment.  Why are task-returning methods special in that they may be removed, but methods that return other types are not?  These problems are all solvable of course; the question is whether solving them is worth delaying or eliminating some other feature that might be of more value to more users.

Comment: @StephenCleary: For example, we might just as well say that a method that returns `IEnumerable<T>` can be replaced by `new T[]{}`, and a method that returns `Func<T>` can be replaced by `()=>default(T)`, and so on; we can keep on doing this all day, but it seems like small bang for fairly large buck.

Comment: @EricLippert: I think `Task`-returning methods are a special case, because they are the *asynchronous equivalent* of a `void`-returning method. Non-generic tasklikes should also be included (so, not `ValueTask<T>`, but a future `ValueTask` would). From an async perspective, `default(Task)` is nonsensical, which is why most of the automocking libraries changed their semantics for that case. I see the argument for `Func<T>` etc, but `Task` is different - logically speaking, it represents the execution of a method; it *doesn't* represent a return value.

Comment: @StephenCleary: `Task<T>` and `Func<T>` both represent values that will be produced in the future; the difference between them is that with a task, that returned value is pushed to the continuation when it is available, and with a func, the value is pulled from it when you want it. And `IEnumerable<T>` is just `Func<T>` that produces more than one value. When used as a return value, they differ only in the details; they are really all the same thing: a time-deferred T, or Ts

Comment: @StephenCleary: So by that logic, should we say that it is a returned `Action` -- the void equivalent of `Func<T>` -- that should have special behaviour?

Comment: I agree that from that perspective, `Task` and `Action` are similar. But there's an important difference - `Action` won't *start* until the future, whereas `Task` (in an asynchronous mindset) has *already* started. So one could give a `null` `Action` semantic meaning, but you can't give a `null` `Task` semantic meaning (again, in an asynchronous mindset). That would be like the caller starting an operation and then the operation just disappears (not completed - just vaporized).

Comment: To put it another way: supporting `Task`-retuning missing methods is similar to assigning an `Action` *variable* to a missing method and having it be a noop. It's not the same as having an `Action`-*returning* method be missing.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a way to use it (or something equivalent) for async methods that return a `Task`?

Same as with any value-returning function: wrap the call in a helper method returning `void`, "returning" the value through a `ref` parameter. Yes, it's clumsy, but this way you're forced to write an initialiser for the return parameter, and that initialiser is how it can be valid even if the call is removed: you can never end up with uninitialised values.

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
public void FooAsync(ref Task task) {
    Func<Task> impl = async () => {
        // ...
    };
    task = impl();
}
```

Usage:

```
public async Task CallFoo() {
    var task = Task.CompletedTask;
    FooAsync(ref task);
    await task;
}
```