# An equivalent of ConditionalAttribute for Task returning async methods

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I'd like to write an `async` method but I'd like it to be callable only if the assembly is compiled with a specific compilation constant.

**ONE WAY**

One way I could do that is by using a pragma directive, i.e. a conditional compilation constant like so:

```
// Callee
#if FOO
  public async Task DoFooAsync()
  {
    ...
  }
#end if

// Caller 1
#if Foo
  // fire and forget
  DoFooAsync();
#endif

// Caller 2
#if Foo
  public async Task<T> DoWork<T>()
  {
    T returnValue = default(T);

    // fire but don't forget
    var fooTask = DoFooAsync();

    // Prepare return value
    returnValue = ...;

    // Not terribly important but what if the caller wants
    // to find out
    if (fooTask.Status == Faulted)
    {
       // do something about it
    }
  }
#endif
```

As you can see, it gets quite messy writing all of this.

**ANOTHER WAY**

The other way of doing this would be to use the [`ConditionalAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute(v=vs.110).aspx). However, from reading the documentation, it appears that the attribute is only applicable to methods that return `void`.

Had that constraint not been there, I would have used the attribute easily like so and that would have made the code so much more neater and nicer to look at and read:

```
// Callee
[Conditional("FOO")]
public Task DoFooAsync() { ... }

// Caller
public async Task<T> DoWork<T>()
{
  // fire and forget
  DoFooAsync();

  // fire but would like to know what happened
  var fooTask = DoFooAsync();

  T t = GetTee();

  if (fooTask.IsFaulted) { ... }

  return t;  

}
```

Though I could have my `async` methods return `void` instead of `Task`, I'd feel very uncomfortable about doing that.

So, is there an equivalent of the `ConditionalAttribute` for methods that want to return a value? Is there one at least for those methods that would like to return just a `Task`?

Comment: You can make your own assembly attribute and construct it dynamically, but I am not sure if this is what you want ? Can you tell us , how do you pass this constant "FOO" , do you want to by constant or dynamically created and then how do you plan to change it ?

Answer (score 1):

What do you expect to happen if you compile it with your condition? Should it return null? Or completed task? Or failed task?

The possible solution is to write your async methods like this:

```
#if FOO
public Task DoFooAsync() => Task.FromResult(0);
#else 
public Task DoFooAsync()
{
    //...
}
#endif
```

So your caller will get empty task in case you compiled the assembly with your conditional symbol.

Comment: On .Net Framework 4.6+, you can use `Task.CompletedTask` instead of `Task.FromResult(0)`.

Comment: @svick You're right. But this answer has nothing to do with the question I am asking. They probably read the question in a hurry.

Comment: I'd imagine the intended effect would be to ignore both the method definition and the call to it at compile time. It's doesn't have to 'return' anything.

Comment: Correction, Apparently it's a tad bit more complicated than not compiling it. Explained by Eric Lippert: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43056131/mark-async-methods-that-just-return-a-task-with-the-conditional-attribute